# Is it possible to display information about each active thread in a threadpool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm currecntly working on a method that prints thread pool metrics. I count overall progress using thread pool methods.

```html
            int progress = Math.round((executor.getCompletedTaskCount() * 100) /
                    executor.getTaskCount());
```

The output looks like this:
**Total progress: 26%; time remained: 3 s; number of threads: 8**

Is it possible to print information about each active thread in a pool? For example, "*thread - 1: 20%, thread - 2: 10%*"

Comment: Cheap shot suggestion: implement your own ThreadPool, or extend an existing one. This way you can easily keep track of your Threads.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. Thank you!

Comment: Even with your own thread pool, how will you know how many percent a given thread has done? The obvious solution would be to expose it somehow in a metrics class or with a method, but if you do you don't need the custom thread pool. You can just check the exposed metrics directly for all threads.